# Wifi much slower after security software download

Tags: wifi, security, vpn

I recently downloaded a vpn and security software (Avast security and windscribe vpn), but my wifi dropped significantly from about 150 mb/s to ~50 mb/s, sometimes much slower.

Even after I deleted the two softwares, my wifi is still at about 50. What can I do to make it go back to normal speeds? I initially thought it had something to do with the mac firewall, but I'm not so sure. 
Thanks

**UPDATE**

never mind, the problem seemed to fix itself somehow. wifi is now back to normal and full functioning

Comment: what security software ???? and what VPN ? can we also see your WiFi

Comment: @Buscar it was Avast security and windscribe vpn

Comment: what do you mean by see my wifi

Comment: hold Option key and click on WiFi, take a screen shot (hide your personal stuff) post it here, or read, RSSI, Tx rate MCS index

Comment: nevermind, the problem seemed to fix itself somehow. wifi is now back to normal and full functioning

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall both would be my recommendation.

- a vpn can send all traffic elsewhere so that has to be slower than letting you unfettered access to sites by the fastest route.
- Mac security software generally opens you up to more vulnerabilities then they patch and slow you down as well.

Comment: nevermind, the problem seemed to fix itself somehow. wifi is now back to normal and full functioning – Atharva Kulkarni 2 hours ago